# i found the deleted row in gridview when i press back button

Tags: asp.net, caching, gridview

i am using asp.net ,in my gridview when i delete any row using "delete command button" and my grid in update panel so it is deleted and doesn't appear but when i click back in browser i found the deleted row  ,so how to make the previous page in browser updated as the current page after deleting?

**QUESTION:** how to avoid that without prevent caching is there another way?

Comment: What do you expect? you requested the previous page and you got it, Its a browser function

Comment: i know but want any way to handle that because if the user found the deleted one it will cause error

Answer (score 3):

You need to prevent the page with the gridview from caching. In your code behind try:

```
Page.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Also you may found some solution to capture the back button via javascript, which I believe is not a good idea. Your code should handle the possibility of user going back.